# Open a link in Google Document with one click using google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-docs

When You make a link in a google document it takes two steps to open the link. (First click on the link and then click once again to open it.)

Is it possible to make a script that opens the link right away when you just click on the link in the document?

Here is the link to the sample sheet with a link in it:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1o0hE6fy2DFRvIddj10H1jECl4ALbs3JxweS8qm63sIc/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A script can only allow you to perform actions for which the endpoint is implemented in the UI

Given that the UI of Google Documents is set up in a way that after clicking on a link text you have to click a second time on the actual URL showing up - unfortunately there is no way to modify this default behavior programmatically.